# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch Error when tried to Fetch data from rest api to react

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-hooks, fetch, flask-restful

I am building an app where the flask rest API takes two strings and gives a floating value as a prediction. Now I am trying to connect to the react app so that the predictions can be shown on a webpage.

Below is the code used to fetch the rest API predictions in react app.

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict?solute=CC(C)(C)Br&solvent=CC(C)(C)O"
    )
      .then((resp) => {
        if (resp.status == 200) {
          return resp.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

In fetch `/predict?solute=CC(C)(C)Br&solvent=CC(C)(C)O` here `solute=CC(C)(C)Br` and `solvent=CC(C)(C)O` are the inputs for the flask rest API to give predictions.

When I am trying to output the result in the console using the above code I am getting error below

[image]

Comment: Is that a working endpoint?

Comment: Yes @assembler. In my console I am getting this ```Access to fetch at 'https://flask-api-test1.herokuapp.com/predict?solute=CC(C)(C)Br&solvent=CC(C)(C)O' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.```

Comment: There you have your response, you are facing a CORS issue.

Comment: How to rectify it @assembler

Comment: Your code is fine, it is the API not returning a proper header. Read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: You need to set up a CORS policy on your Flask app - I've used this extension before - https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is a CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) issue.  When you have a separate backend (your Flask API) and front end (your React SPA), the requests to the backend are coming from a different origin than the API.  As you can imagine, allowing requests from *any* origin to your API may create some vulnerabilities, so the default behavior is to *not allow* cross origin requests.  You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

By using a Flask extension such as [Flask-CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), you'll be able to define a CORS policy for your API that will either allow all origins (using a wildcard - `*`), or you can specify which origins are allowed, and in some cases which endpoints have which CORS policies.  The actual implementation will vary based on your framework and the packages/extensions you use, but most packages/extensions make it easy to apply simply CORS policies to your API.